# "Neither he had" vs "he neither had"

Tags: grammar, word-order

Example:

> Despite the fact he was nearing his thirties and got stressed a lot at
>   work, he still had a full head of hair. No thinning at all. **[Neither/he]** had wrinkles, and his face was still long and thin—not the least
>   sign of weight gain.

Should it be *neither he* or *he neither*? If both are grammatically incorrect, what's the right option?

Comment: You're not allowing for the possibility that they're both ungrammatical. Which is actually the case.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth how about now?

Comment: Neither of your alternatives are natural English. If you insist on squeezing in the word ***neither*** with no corresponding ***nor***, you could use something like *"Neither did he have any wrinkles..."*, but to be honest none of it is likely to work very well in this exact context.

Comment: ...also note that the informal/colloquial phrasing *got stressed a lot at work* is completely out of kilter with the rest of the text (which is formal/literary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Neither** is a conjunction, implying that there are two or more negative statements in play. I would reword your example as

> Despite the fact he was nearing his thirties and got stressed a lot at work, he still had a full head of hair. No thinning at all. **Nor did he have** wrinkles, and his face was still long and thin—not the least sign of weight gain.

**[Edit]**

But even *that* is awkward. Per the comments below, I would suggest rewriting the whole paragraph:

> Despite the fact he was nearing his thirties and got stressed a lot at work, he still had a full head of hair; no thinning at all. He had no wrinkles, and his face was still long and thin -- not the least sign of weight gain.

Comment: The interposed fragment makes the '... Nor did he' not a natural choice here, as the positive statement '... he still had a full head of hair' has perhaps more claim to being the antecedent.

Comment: True. Probably the whole paragraph could use a rewrite.

Comment: Constructions like "*Neither had he a chicken, nor a pot to cook it in.*" look to peak around 1750 on Google ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neither+had+he+a&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cneither%20had%20he%20a%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

Neither of them are grammatically correct. *Neither* is used when you have two or more 'options' to choose from. In this case you would say:

> Nor did he have wrinkles

You could also say:

> He did not have wrinkles, either

Comment: “Neither did he have wrinkles” is just fine when there was an earlier negation. Also, *neither* is better used as a singular.

Comment: Give me an example of neither as a singular

Comment: I’d quite like to see that, too. In this conjunctive use, neither _neither_ nor _nor_ (is there an echo here?) can be used if there is only one ‘option’ in play, as far as I can think of. They both imply that two or more things are being negated. But then as a pronoun/determiner, it certainly is singular, and “Neither of them are grammatically correct” is ungrammatical to me.

Comment: Neither one of you is trying hard if you can't think of a singular sentence with _neither_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *Neither* at the start of a clause followed by inversion is hardly uncommon. §1 *I’m not going, and neither is she.* §2 *He does not eat them; neither does he hunt or eat wild animals.* §3 *Neither did I go because I feared what might be done to me if I refused.* §4 *Neither was he counted one of the queen’s men.* §5 *She was not pushed by the wind, and neither did it carry her.* §6 *There was no point in going on, and he couldn’t go up. Neither could he return to his
cell, because the corpse was still there, and he thought he’d go mad if he had to see it again.*

Comment: @tchrist Every single one of those examples imply (or explicitly say) that there are two or more things being negated. The verb in the sentence is singular, but that’s not what I (or Elendil, if I understand correctly) was talking about. In §1, the two things are _I go_ and _she goes_; in §2, they’re _he eats them_, _he hunts_, and _he eats wild animals_; etc. I thought in your first comment you meant that _neither_ could/should be used when only one action was mentioned in the scope of the general negating, which is where I would use _not_, and thus couldn’t think of any examples.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I guess I misunderstood you then. I also find *neither of them are* to be ungrammatical for me. For singular examples of *neither*, I submit: §1 *In happy hour did Eorl ride from the North, and never has any league of peoples been more blessed, so that **neither has** ever failed the other, nor shall fail.* §2 *Easterners hold gods in awe, denying us any humanity. Dragaerans have the attitude that godhood is a skill, like sorcery, and there’s nothing more to it than that. **Neither is** correct.* (continued)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet §3 *I knew then that I had seen Tzadkiel before I helped Sidero and the rest catch him as Zak, and that the male form I saw was no more true (though no less) than the winged woman whose glance had stunned me then, and that **neither was** more true, or less, than the animal shape that had saved me when Purn had tried to kill me outside his cage.* §4 *Just now, though, **neither of those was** fit for human habitation.* §5 *At last I said, “Without mentioning a matter **neither of us wishes** to discuss, I cannot help but remark that you appear to have changed a great deal.”*

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Dude, I’m not disagreeing with you. :(  I’m just supporting my initial comment at the top, showing uses of *neither* without *nor*, and then showing examples of *neither* used with a singular verb.