# "Neither should we…" vs "We should neither…"

Tags: grammaticality, neither-nor

I have some grammar confusion about the sentences below.

In which ways are the following sentences correct?

> Neither should we cut any trees nor burn them.
>
> We should neither cut any trees nor burn them.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186628/neither-he-had-vs-he-neither-had

Comment: If you are interested in maintaining strict parallelism, you can say "Neither should we cut any trees nor should we burn them" in the first case and "We should neither cut any trees nor burn them" in the second. The rationale here is that in the first case the **neither** proposition (the content between _neither_ and _nor_) comprehends "should we cut any trees," whereas in the second case the **neither** proposition comprehends "cut any trees." The parallel forms of these two propositions are, respectively, "should we burn them" and "burn them."

Comment: Also related: ["Should either be" or "should be either"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9123/should-either-be-or-should-be-either).

Answer (score 2):

The "neither...nor..." construction is used [to conjoin (or connect) two alternatives](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either). Both of those sentences are correct in that sense.

In casual speech, "We should neither cut any trees nor burn them" is more likely.

"Neither should we cut any trees nor burn them" sounds as though you are continuing on a conversation. For example,

```
A: We shouldn't sell trees.
B: Neither should we cut any trees nor burn them!
```

In formal writing, you might want to pay attention to [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)). For example, notice that the construction looks like "neither X nor Y". Parallelism is simply making both X and Y of the same *grammatical type*. That is, in "We should neither **cut any trees** nor **burn them**", both *cut any trees* and *burn them* are verb phrases (verbs and their direct object). However, in "Neither **should we cut any trees** nor **burn them**", *should we cut any trees* is a clause (modal, subject, main verb, and object) and *burn them* is a simple verb phrase (without the modal or the subject). If we were to maintain parallelism, we might want to make the second conjunct (Y) a clause as well, as in "Neither **should we cut any trees** nor **should we burn them**".

Comment: I'd argue that 'We should not kill. Neither should we steal nor destroy.' is ungrammatical, requiring an 'or'.

Comment: Repeating the "should we" is pointless and does nothing to preserve parallel structure, which is the sole reason the ellipsis is possible.

Comment: When the *neither* is sentence-initial it is referring backwards to a previous sentence. When it is after the auxiliary verb, it refers forwards to two alternatives.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Interesting. How do you find the sentence "we should neither steal or destory"?

Comment: @KarlG Perhaps the avoidance of ellipsis is a person stylistic choice rather than a hard rule, as it appears to be framed in my answer. I concede that my regard towards parallelism has more to do with personal aesthetic than formal writing.

Comment: @Araucaria Are you making reference to the example in the original post? I think that was what I was trying to get at there. To be sure, a sentence initial *neitter* (for my own idiolect) has the effect of referring backwards in the discourse for other possible alternatives.

Comment: 'We should neither steal nor destroy' is obviously needed in this case. // How would you assess 'We should not eat nor drink this morning.'?